# How to have two pure virtual methods with the same name but different return types

Tags: c++, overloading, multiple-inheritance, pure-virtual

I've got an interface `A` which is publicly available, and a back-end implementation class `C`, like so:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct C : public A
{
    virtual void f() override
    {
    }
};
```

I would like to gradually migrate to a new interface, `B`.  `B` will have the same methods, however, the return types might be different.  I would like my implemetation class to implement both `A` and `B` so that legacy code can keep using `A` until it is migrated, but new code can be written with `B`.  I know that if I have two pure virtual methods with exactly the same signature, I only need one override in my implementation class.  But if they differ by return type, I don't know how to do it...

```
struct A
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct B
{
    virtual int f() = 0;
};


struct C : public A, public B
{
    // How do I implement both versions of f() here??
};
```

Comment: You cannot overload based on return value alone.  You need to give `B::f()` a different set of parameters, or rename it to something else.

Comment: You don't - you, you implement classes D and E that implement the various `f()`'s and then inherit those.

Comment: even if you were to have both, `cObj.f()` would be ambiguous

Comment: @vu1p3n0x not if you pass an A or B pointer / reference to an object it's not

Comment: @vu1p3n0x surprisingly, it is not.

Comment: Try templatizing your interface so that the same interface can be used for different data type as return values

Comment: @vu1p3n0x ok, I was thinking about something else. Nevermind and let's pretend it never happened.

Comment: Suppose you are writing the new code that is supposed to use the `B` interface via `C`. How do you expect the new code to tell `C` that the `B` interface is to be used? (Once you've answered that: what benefit are you gaining by using a single class with both interfaces?)

Comment: @Maddy Can you explain how that generalization (templatisation?) would work?

Answer (score 0):

This at least compiles with VS2017:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct A2: public A
{
    void f() { Af(); }
    virtual void Af() = 0;
};

struct B
{
    virtual int f() = 0;
};

struct B2 : public B
{
    int f() { return Bf(); }
    virtual int Bf() = 0;
};

struct C : public A2, public B2
{
    void Af() {}
    int Bf() { return 42; }
};
```

Edit: Could not add this a comment on Paul Accisano's own answer, so I put it here.

Modifying Paul's answer slightly. By making the unused default parameter a protected class, you still have correct type checking, and avoid the potential for a type conflict with another member function.

```
struct A
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct B
{
protected:
    class disambiguator {};
public:
    virtual int f(disambiguator ignoreMe = disambiguator()) = 0;
};


struct C : public A, public B
{
    virtual void f() override {}
    virtual int f(disambiguator ignoreMe) override { return 42; }
};

A *createA() { return new C; }
B *createB() { return new C; }
```

One application for this could be the gradual migration from raw pointers to smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is

```
struct A {}
struct B {}
struct OldImpl : public A {}
struct NewImpl : public B {}
struct Combined : public AImpl, public BImpl {}
```

You can then pass the combined into anything that wants an A or a B.
The problem with this is that your OldImpl and NewImpl are completely separate.  They're not allowed to interact with each other; meaning you can't call `setFoo()` in A and get the same value in `getFoo()` in B.  Which is probably not what you want from what you described.

To resolve this, don't create a 2nd interface.  It wouldn't work anyway because where a `xxx()` might be void now, and an int later, you probably want to do something with the return value.  If you really want to do it in baby steps, create a branch, change a single functions return value, test it, merge it in, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the good responses!  But I did figure out my own solution: good old optional parameters!

```
struct A
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct B
{
    virtual int f(int ignoreMe = 0) = 0;
};


struct C : public A, public B
{
    virtual void f() override {}
    virtual int f(int) override {}
};
```

No ambiguity for external users using `A` or `B`, and no parameters need to change.  No ambiguity internally either because parameter is non-optional in the implementation class.  The optional parameter can be removed, along with `A`, once migration is complete.

Comment: Very hackish design!